# Docker Container CPU Usage

Tags: docker, cpu-usage

I am using the docker remote API to retrieve stats of my running containers. For CPU usage I get for example this:

```
"cpu_stats": {
    "cpu_usage": {
      "total_usage": 13039191340,
      "percpu_usage": [
        13039191340
      ],
      "usage_in_kernelmode": 420000000,
      "usage_in_usermode": 10480000000
    },
    "system_cpu_usage": 8.8930204e+14,
    "throttling_data": {
      "periods": 0,
      "throttled_periods": 0,
      "throttled_time": 0
    }
  }
```

How can I calculate the CPU usage in percent? When I divide "usage_in_kernelmode" with "total_usage" I get a similar result as the `docker stats` command, but is this the right way to do it?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ultimately, it comes down to what CPU usage you want to measure.

The usage states are in cycles. User cycles are those spent in executing applications, including system applications (like daemons) executing in user space. Kernel cycles are those spent in executing *fundamental* OS or driver functions. Non-fundamental OS functions execute in user space. The unaccounted for cycles are probably idle cycles, those spent doing nothing useful.

So total CPU percent usage is (kernel+user)/(idle+kernel+user)*100. User CPU usage is (user))/(idle+kernel+user)*100. And you can guess the equation for system % usage.

system_cpu_usage puzzles me. If it, instead of total_usage, refers to total cycles, then replace (idle+kernel+user) with that. What puzzles me is if system_cpu_usage is total usage, then what the heck is total_usage?

Comment: Hey, thanks Taylor :) I figured it out, finally, but only by looking into the code of docker stats :D

"total_usage" seems to be the computing time my application/container consumed. You get another property "precpu_stats", which looks exactly the same like "cpu_stats", but the metrics are from the previous tick. I can then calculate delta-total_usage and delta-system_usage and the final solution is percent = (delta-total_usage / delta-system_usage) * percpu_usage.length * 100.0

Comment: @alsdkjasdlkja do you know why this should be multiplied by the number of CPUs? cause total_usage is the total of all percpu_usage numbers, so it already factors all the CPUs.

Comment: @rags 
 Hey, you can have a look at the docker-cli implementation: https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/bf4a96e5640f86860e68622d2498039d86bf5714/cli/command/container/stats_helpers.go#L166. Maybe I read it wrong, maybe it is (or was... half a decade passed) flawed :)

Comment: @alsdkjasdlkja Yeah, they do the same there, I've asked them to review it: https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/2134#issuecomment-558571695

Comment: Hello, CPU usage of host is received in docker stats command, can you provide how can we get %CPU usage of docker container out of allowed CPU for container. This will help to get alerts for high CPU usage and intimate that we should increase allowed CPU of container from HOST. Same I have asked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63813491/docker-container-cpu-usage-monitoring